# Application Insights Behind a Firewall

Tags: asp.net, firewall, azure-devops, obsolete, azure-application-insights

I'm having issues getting application insights to report data to Visual Studio Online from behind our firewall. I opened the firewall rules noted in [this article](http://stuartpreston.net/2014/07/microsoft-application-insights-connecting-from-behind-the-firewall/) but it didn't make a difference. I've uninstalled and reinstalled several times. The only thing that is showing up in the Operations Logs is that it's periodically purging items in the "AppDiagnostics" queue since exceed the maximum allowed size of 15 MB (full error below).

Get-WebApplicationMonitoringStatus shows all the applications I would expect to be monitored being monitored.

The health service has removed some items from the send queue for management group "AppDiagnostics" since it exceeded the maximum allowed size of 15 megabytes.

Answer (score 1):

The IP addresses and hosts that you need to configure/allow are officially documented here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-ip-addresses

I'd copy and paste the "relevant" portions, but

1. there's a huge number of them depending on what you want/need to do and
2. then they'd be wrong here whenever the above doc is updated